# Can One Bash Script Launch Multiple Other Bash Scripts?

Tags: linux, bash

I currently have a Bash Script ("Bash Script 1") that executes a PHP file. I would like to have a Bash script that can launch multiple instances of "Bash Script 1" and let them run at the same time.

Is this possible and how might I go about this?

Any thoughts or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run them in the background, just like you would in an interactive shell.

```
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &
wait # Wait for all background commands to finish
```

The commands can be just about anything, not just other bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat the same command:

```
N=10 # number of repetitions
for i in $(seq $N)
do
    bash_script_1&
done
```

Comment: +1, though there's no real need to call out to `seq`; you might as well use built-in Bash features, like `for ((i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i))` or `for i in {1..10}`.

Comment: Maybe, but unfortunately `{1..$N}` does not work if you want to use a variable